# How to consume a WSDL webservice in a .NET Core project?

Tags: .net-core, wsdl

I have a project in .NET Cre that needs to consume a WSDL webservice.

I've set up the URI, Services, Operation, but when I create an instance of the operation class, I see no methods, only the properties. No method to pass parameters and receive feedback from webservice.

Comment: By wsdl service, you mean SOAP? Which version? Could you add your code? How do you reference the service in your project?

Comment: I right-clicked the Solution > Add > Connected Service > WCF Web Service Reference Provider. I set the URI, Service and Operation

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/70 Do use the command line utility to generate the wrapper. It would also tell what happened if failed.